# Inconsistent HTMLBody on a Inline response in Outlook

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

I have a ribbon button that, on click, gets the HTMLBody and modifies it. However, I keep seeing issues with this when getting the HtmlBody for an inline reponse.

This is how I fetch it

```
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Explorer exp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveExplorer();
        if (exp.ActiveInlineResponse != null)
        {
            var body = exp.ActiveInlineResponse.HTMlBody;
        }
```

However, when I first click reply and click the button I get a fairly short HTMLBody (just the body of the original message like so

```
<div dir=\"ltr\">test</div>\r\n"
```

But when I click again I get a very large HTML Body that looks like a formatted document like this (this is just a snippet, its quite large)

```
<html xmlns:v=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml\" xmlns:o=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office\" xmlns:w=\"urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word\" xmlns:m=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/office/2004/12/omml\" xmlns=\"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40\"><head><meta name=ProgId content=Word.Document><meta name=Generator content=\"Microsoft Word 15\"><meta name=Originator content=\"Microsoft Word 15\"><link rel=File-List href=\"cid:filelist.xml@01D22FA2.0744EA10\"><link rel=Edit-Time-Data href=\"cid:editdata.mso\"><!--[if !mso]><style>v\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\r\no\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\r\nw\\:* {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\r\n.shape {behavior:url(#default#VML);}\r\n</style><![endif]--><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\r\n<o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\r\n<o:AllowPNG/>\r\n</o:OfficeDocumentSettings>\r\n</xml><![endif]--><link rel=themeData href=\"~~themedata~~\"><link rel=colorSchemeMapping href=\"~~colorschememapping~~\"><!--[if gte mso 9]><xml>\r\n<w:WordDocument>\r\n<w:TrackMoves/>\r\n<w:TrackFormat
ting/>\r\n<w:EnvelopeVis/>\r\n
```

Is there a reason why these are different each time? IS this the wrong way to access the html body for an inline response? If so, how?

Thanks!